# Heroku DB Query running thousands of times for 4 records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Not really sure what is going on.  I have an application that worked fine until about a week ago.  Now when I try to load a specific page that displays data it runs this query thousands of times and eventually times out.  There are only 4 records that meet these criteria, and the query itself was working fine with as many as 4k + records (with some downtime but it is a personal app).

This is the output, over and over

```
...
2019-08-01T21:14:28.443577+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d861f61-b6eb-42a8-b3d2-a9132d974644]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "steps" WHERE (user_id = 1 AND status = 1)
...
```

The number in brackets changes but everything else just keeps running until it times out.  I'm not sure if I have to dump a cache or something, never had this issue and I cannot figure out why it just keeps running this even though at the moment, if I run query on the db it returns 4 records.

This is the method generating the query, it hasn't changed

```
  # Returns the user's grade to the profile view
  def get_grade(user)
    completed_steps = Step.where("user_id = ? AND status = ?", user, 1)
    failed_steps    = Step.where("user_id = ? AND status = ?", user, 2)
    ongoing_steps   = Step.where("user_id = ? AND status = ?", user, 0)
    all_steps = completed_steps.count.to_f + failed_steps.count.to_f

    if all_steps.to_f > 0
      grade = completed_steps.count.to_f / all_steps * 100
      return grade.to_i
    else
      grade = 0
      return grade.to_i
    end
  end
```

Comment: How many users are in the database? Is there something else you're iterating over many times that would cause `get_grade` to be called repeatedly?

Comment: No, only 1 user as well, and this is not getting called in any kind of a loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this isn't your question, but I'm just wondering...

If you have a `status` `enum` in your `Step` model, couldn't you do:

```
# Returns the user's grade to the profile view
def get_grade(user)
  completed_steps = user.steps.completed?.count
  failed_steps    = user.steps.failed?.count
  all_steps       = completed_steps + failed_steps

  return ((completed_steps.to_f / all_steps) * 100).to_i if all_steps > 0
  0
end
```

Apologies, it was just a random observation.

Comment: Never thought of that but I'll give it a try

Comment: So not at all really sure what was creating the issue for me.  But I made this change because it looked cleaner and the page loaded without any issues.

Comment: Hm. Curious. Well, glad you got unstuck!